# Any good books for Infinite Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I wanted to know about some good, free books on Infinite Series.

Comment: Aimed at which level?

Comment: Do you need a whole book?  Knopp's Theory & Application of infinite series would have just about everything you'd ever need to know, and its cheap from Dover.   If you want examples and basic skills in working with infinite series, I'd recomment Murray R Speigel's Schaum's Advanced Calculus, which is a lot more than just infinite series, but probably enough and more for an undergrad analysis class. ( that's cheap too!)

Comment: Thanks user247608 but i have already used R Spiegels Adv. Calc. And completlh mastered integrals.

Comment: You need to answer @user170039 's question; there is really no good answer unless we know what you know and what not.  From the tone of the question I can surmise that 1) you need a book on elementary real analysis and 2) you have *not* "mastered integrals".  There is no way one can "master integrals", whatever that means, but not have a good grounding on sequences and series.

Comment: One more thing: you mention poverty.  Gladly, there are hordes of high quality free lecture notes and books on analysis available on the Internet.  As soon as you can provide us information on your level (read: what you have studied so far, meaning what kind of topics you have successfully solved many, many problems in), people will be able to link tons of free notes.

Comment: @guest if u say so cn u provide some links and also i m not saying that i dont know anything about sequences and series but I am saying that i want to know more about them. On the point of integrals I wanted to say that i have reached up to a level of mastering integrals from Adv. Calc.

Comment: I have Knopp’s book. It is pretty good

Answer (score 4):

Two sources come to mind: first, Knopp's Theory and application of infinite series like user247608 suggested (very cheap), and Pete Clark's free notes which can be found here: [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/3100supp.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/3100supp.pdf)